# trying to combine two dates causes app to crash

Tags: swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to trigger notification on specific saved time in database and on specific day which is Friday as shown below, but every time I try to save new reminder it tells me `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and I'm sure it contains data and it's not nil even though I tried to handle nil, still the app crash, however when I try to fire notification without combining dates like this `localNotification.fireDate = reminders.time!` the app is not crashed and it works just fine.

I guess the problem in combineDate function, how I can solve this problem?

```
   func combineDate(time: NSDate?) -> NSDate{

            let gregorianCalendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!

            let time: NSDateComponents = gregorianCalendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: time!)
            time.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
            let timeCombiner: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
            timeCombiner.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
            timeCombiner.hour = time.hour
            timeCombiner.minute = time.minute
            timeCombiner.second = 00
             timeCombiner.weekday = 6
            let combinedDate: NSDate = gregorianCalendar.dateFromComponents(components3)!

            return combinedDate

    }


    func createLocalNotification(){

        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()

        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
     localNotification.fireDate = combineDate(reminders.time!)

 localNotification.alertBody = reminders.name!

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)




    }
```

[image]

Comment: *"I'm sure it contains data and it's not nil"*: Why are you sure? What's your evidence? The error message is telling you the exact opposite.

Comment: Try rewriting both functions without using the `!` anywhere. Instead use `if let` and `guard let`.

Comment: well after i open the app again the reminder table is reloaded with the reminder i tried to saved and when I open that reminder the view loads just fine with data that I saved, and as I mentioned when i replace  `localNotification.fireDate = combineDate(reminders.time!)` with  `localNotification.fireDate = reminders.time!` no problem happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1):

still the reason of causing all this mass unknown however I solved it by checking if reminder managed object is not equal to nil then try to fire notification

```
 func createLocalNotification(){

        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()

        localNotification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
if reminder != nil{
     localNotification.fireDate = combineDate(reminders.time!)
}

 localNotification.alertBody = reminders.name!

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)




    }
```